# Передача значения с одного окна в другое в javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Делаю игру по типу монополии, и возник вопрос над которым уже сижу пару дней. Вообщем, при создании новой игры (нажатия кнопки "Новая игра"), вылазит меню, в котором игрок должен выбрать сколько игроков должно быть в его игре и, по желанию, может задать им имена. Класс новой игры в свою очередь должен вернуть коллекцию имен игроков. Проблема заключается в том, что в главной проге, когда я нажимаю на кнопку, ей сразу после открытия окна передается нулл значение и проходит дальше, где у меня стоит проверка на нулл.

```
arrayLengthCounter = arr.size();
System.out.println(arrayLengthCounter);
  if(arr != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLengthCounter; i++) {
      playerHBox = addPlayerHBox();
      System.out.println("hbox created");
    }
}
```

После этого оно проходит проверку, а после того когда я задаю значение в окне, оно возращается переменной в мейне, но через цикл больше не проходит и больше ничего не создает. Второй вариант у меня был с тем чтобы класс новой игры возращал сразу готовые hbox'ы в заданном колличестве, но проблема осталась той же, значения просто не добавлялись в лейаут.

```
if(hueHueBox != null){
  layout.getChildren().addAll(hueHueBox);
}
```

И ладно бы если бы только в новой игре была такая проблема, но такая же имеется и при покупке каких-либо зданий, потому что там аналогичный механизм выполнения.

```
buyPanelHouse.setOnAction(e -> {
  int n = buyPanelHouseMenu.display();
  System.out.println(n);
  if(n == 1){
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(120,30); //должен просто создаться прямоугольник в окне
    r.setFill(Color.RED);
    GridPane.setConstraints(r, 0,0);
    hBoxGridPaneProcess.getChildren().addAll(r);
  }
});
```

Буду признателен за любую помощь и/или советы

Класс создания окна:

```
    import javafx.scene.text.Text;
    import javafx.stage.*;
    import javafx.scene.*;
    import javafx.scene.layout.*;
    import javafx.scene.control.*;
    import javafx.geometry.*;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import static java.lang.Double.MAX_VALUE;

public class createMenuBox {

private static int n;
private  static HBox hueHueBox = null;

public static HBox display() {

    Stage window = new Stage();
    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
    TextField[] tfArr = new TextField[5];
    ArrayList<String> returnArr = new ArrayList<>();

    window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    window.setTitle("Подготовка");

    ChoiceBox<Integer> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>();



    Scene scene = new Scene(layout,400, 500);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();

    //default option
    choiceBox.getItems().addAll(2,3,4,5);
    choiceBox.setValue(2);
    choiceBox.setMaxSize(MAX_VALUE, MAX_VALUE);

    Text windowTitle = new Text("Задайте колличество игроков");
    Text windowSecondTitle = new Text("Отличный выбор!");
    Text playerNameTitle = new Text("Нажмите, если вам не нравятся стандартные имена");
    Text startButtonTitle = new Text("Нажмите, если считаете себя готовым");
    Text startButtonSecondTitle = new Text("Пожалуйста, не оставляйте поля пустыми");

    layout.getChildren().addAll(windowTitle);

    Button btn = new Button("Сохранить");
    layout.getChildren().addAll(choiceBox, btn);
    Button buttonSetNames = new Button("Задать имена");
    Button startBtn = new Button("Готово");
    startBtn.setMaxSize(MAX_VALUE, MAX_VALUE);
    btn.setMaxSize(MAX_VALUE, MAX_VALUE);
    btn.setOnAction(e -> {
        getChoice(choiceBox);
        System.out.println(n);
        layout.getChildren().remove(windowTitle);
        layout.getChildren().add(windowSecondTitle);
        layout.getChildren().add(buttonSetNames);
        buttonSetNames.setMaxSize(MAX_VALUE, MAX_VALUE);
        layout.getChildren().add(playerNameTitle);
        layout.getChildren().add(startBtn);
        layout.getChildren().add(startButtonTitle);
        startBtn.setOnAction(ee -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (tfArr[i] == null){
                    returnArr.add(i, ("Игрок-" + (i+1)));
                }
                System.out.println(returnArr.get(i));
            }

            if(returnArr != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < returnArr.size(); i++) {
                    hueHueBox = Main.addPlayerHBox();
                    System.out.println("hbox created");
                }
            }

            window.close();
        });
        choiceBox.setDisable(true);
        btn.setDisable(true);
    });
    buttonSetNames.setOnAction(e -> {
        layout.getChildren().remove(startButtonTitle);
        layout.getChildren().remove(playerNameTitle);
        layout.getChildren().remove(windowSecondTitle);
        layout.getChildren().remove(startBtn);
        buttonSetNames.setDisable(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            tfArr[i] = new TextField();
            layout.getChildren().add(tfArr[i]);
        }
        startBtn.setMaxSize(MAX_VALUE, MAX_VALUE);
        layout.getChildren().add(startBtn);
        layout.getChildren().add(startButtonSecondTitle);

        startBtn.setOnAction(ee -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                returnArr.add(i, tfArr[i].getText());
                if (tfArr[i].getText().trim().isEmpty()){
                    returnArr.add(i, ("Игрок-" + (i+1)));
                }
                System.out.println(returnArr.get(i));
            }

            if(returnArr != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < returnArr.size(); i++) {
                    hueHueBox = Main.addPlayerHBox();
                    System.out.println("hbox created");
                }
            }

            window.close();
        });
    });

        return hueHueBox;
}

  private static void getChoice(ChoiceBox<Integer> choiceBox) {
      n = choiceBox.getValue();
  }
}
```

Comment: Все это занятно, но ничего не понятно. Вы создаете модальное окно и хотите из него получить значения? Каким способом создаете окно? fxml, или руками? Лучше выложите код с созданием окна.

Comment: Создаю руками. Класс создания окна выглядит следующим образом: (добавил в вопрос)

Comment: Так. Я тебе дам совет, но только ты не обижайся. Тут проблема не только и не столько в логике, сколько в оформлении. 1) Классы пишутся с большой буквы и именем обычно обозначают объект а не действие. 2) Вложенные друг в друга лямбды это плохо и не читаемо. Хотя бы перенеси их в отдельные методы.

Comment: За эти наставления конечно спасибо, но я не совсем понял как это поможет в разрешении самой проблемы? Если я классы с большой напишу, все заработает?